# Jenkins: Check if a file was changed by svn update

Tags: python, svn, jenkins, pip

I would like to know if a certain file changed since the last checkout - after jenkins has checked my repository out of svn. Since the build process starts with jenkins updating the workspace i need to find out then and cant check via *svn status -u*.

Background here is that i want check if the file containing the project requirements (requirements.txt) was altered and in this case update the environment (virtualenv).

Would i have to store the revision number of the last checkout and compare it with the output of *svn log requirements.txt* or *svn diff* against that revision?

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to emulate here your case

```
z:\j-wc>svn ls -v .
      2 Badger                окт 19 05:40 ./
      2 Badger             13 окт 19 05:40 a.txt
      2 Badger             14 окт 19 05:40 requirements.txt
```

j-wc is Working Copy, updated to older revision of repo, than current HEAD

```
z:\j-wc>svn ls -v file:///Z:/repo/trunk
      5 Badger                окт 19 05:44 ./
      2 Badger             13 окт 19 05:40 a.txt
      5 Badger             39 окт 19 05:44 b.txt
      4 Badger             21 окт 19 05:43 requirements.txt
```

some time ago

If (before `svn up`) I have to know "Will I get changes in requirements.txt?" I'll try

`z:\j-wc>svn diff -r "BASE":"HEAD" requirements.txt | wc -l`. If changes was happened, diff outputs results (diff inside WC with local file allow to use permanent symbolic revision names BASE+HEAD), no changes == no output

```
z:\j-wc>svn diff -r "BASE":"HEAD" requirements.txt
Index: requirements.txt
===================================================================
--- requirements.txt    (working copy)
+++ requirements.txt    (revision 5)
@@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
 Req 1
 Req 2
+Req 3
```

Comment: But this does only work before svn up, right? When jenkins executes the build-step in which i might need to update the environment it already has done the svn up. I'm thinkng, probably i should look more in the direction of pip than svn here.